# Как обновить контент ajax-ом при авторизации пользователя через devise?

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails

Есть вот такая конструкция на главной странице, авторизация через модальное окно с помощью json. Как сделать чтобы при авторизации вывелись li с current_user, без перезагрузки страницы

```
      <% if current_user %>
          <li><a><%= "Hello, #{current_user.fullname}" %></a></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
      <li><a href="#create_user_modal" class="modal_fancy">Регистрация</a></li>
      <li><a href="#login_modal" class="modal_fancy">Вход</a></li>
      <% end %>
```

Jquery обработка вывода ошибок через json

```
$("#login ").bind("ajax:success", function(event, xhr, settings){

});

  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      respond_to :html, :json
  end
```

Ruby 2.2
Rails 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не рекомендую так делать. Вашему сайту придется знать, что именно и как именно менять при успешном входе. Это stateful-решение, а им свойственен нелинейный рост по сложности поддержки. С развитием проекта этот код вам будет все тяжелее и тяжелее поддерживать. Неоправданно тяжелее.

Предпочитайте stateless-решения. Перезагрузите страницу - можно через turbolinks, если хотите перезагрузить моментально для пользователя, без белого экрана пустой страницы.

Comment: А как перезагрузить через  turbolinks?

Comment: Подключите по инструкции - https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/. В js можете вставить `Turbolinks.visit(window.location)`. Хотя если turbolinks подключить, соблюдая рекомендации в readme - можно обойтись без ручной обработки каждой формы - turbolinks возьмет на себя плавные переходы по ссылкам на сайте и плавные редиректы - при отправке форм в том числе.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, все таки жаль, что так сложно все с ajax

Comment: Сложность не в самом ajax, а в stateful-обновлении интерфейса. Во фронтенде, пока не стал популярным reactjs - с js-фреймворками того времени была каша как раз из-за их stateful-ориентированности. У вас сайты на Ruby on Rails, и это здорово - там есть turbolinks и jquery_ujs, которые помогают элегнатно обновлять интерфейс аяксово, не погружаясь в дебри фронтенда.